# Can I add a Python compiler/interpreter in a NextJS application, for user to run and test small Python code?

Tags: python, next.js

I am building an educational application in NextJS (v13), where I would like to allow user to write and run/test small Python code. I want to build somewhat like an online compiler/interpreter. Is that possible? If so, could someone point me in the right direction and/or resources?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, I would recommend running the Python code in the browser using Pyodide instead of the server. That's what I did for my educational Python site https://futurecoder.io/. You don't have to worry about security or server costs. You can email me for further guidance about that.

Comment: That sounds really interesting. Could you help me locate your mail address? I would like to learn more about your work

Comment: It's on https://github.com/alexmojaki